# v-for using Map data structure and v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know it is possible to use Map with v-for, but say, is it possible to use the values [key, value] as v-model?

Ex:

```
<input v-for="[key, value] in map" :key="key" v-model="key"></input>
...
...
...
data(){
    return {
        map: new Map([['cool thing 1', 'cool thing 2'], ...])
    }
}
```

Does Vue3 support this natively?

If not, what could be done?

To be more precise i want to use the key and value thenselves as v-model in inputs

Comment: Reactivity is supported for Map in Vue3. Does your code give any errors? Or it just does not work?

Comment: Did you try `v-model="map[key]"` ?

Comment: @Chin.Udara i have no errors actually, however to be more precise here i'm trying to use the key itself as a v-model. My idea its basically the user can input both key and value for a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Vue has only two limitations on what can be used with `v-model`

1. the expression must be valid "left side" for assignment (because `v-model="xxx"` is same as `:value="xxx" @input="xxx = $event"`)
2. Both pairs - `(key, value)` when iterating objects and `(value, index)` when iterating arrays are local temp variables of the loop so it does not make any sense to use them in the `v-model`. If you try that you will get a warning: `You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable.`

So you need to make a step back and use the original object/array with `v-model`

Arrays: `v-model="arr[index]"`

Objects/Maps: `v-model="map[key]"`

### Update

> My idea its basically the user can input both key and value for a map

That is a bad idea for a few reasons. First, as said before `key` variable is a local temp variable in the loop so using it in `v-model` is not possible. Second (again - as said before) whatever you put inside `v-model` must be "assignable". `Map` object [is not assignable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#setting_object_properties) - you must use a `set` method to set a value of particular key. So `v-model` is not an option here (you must use events instead). On top of that, Map does not allow duplicate keys so letting users freely edit the keys is recipe for a very weird UX....

Comment: i have no errors actually, however to be more precise here i'm trying to use the key itself as a v-model. My idea its basically the user can input both key and value for a map